# How to execute an installer executable on a remote machine with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, winrm

I'm trying to automate the upgrading of Spotfire BI system on our Windows servers.

The instructions show a command that can be used to silently install which states the location of the executable file followed by all the required options/parameters as shown with this example:

```
install.exe INSTALLDIR="<node manager installation dir>" NODEMANAGER_REGISTRATION_PORT=9080 NODEMANAGER_COMMUNICATION_PORT=9443 SERVER_NAME=SpotfireServerName SERVER_BACKEND_REGISTRATION_PORT=9080 SERVER_BACKEND_COMMUNICATION_PORT=9443 NODEMANAGER_HOST_NAMES=NodeManagerHostNames NODEMANAGER_HOST=NodeManagerHost -silent -log "C:\Users\user\Log file.log"
```

This does work, and as long as it preceded by the call operator (&), it runs well in PowerShell. However, I can't get it to work when running this on a remote server:

```
 function nodeManagerUpgrade {
    Param([String]$ServiceName1,
    [String]$InstallDirectory,
    [String]$HostNames1
    )

    Stop-Service $ServiceName1

    # this is the line that fails
    & "X:/downloads/spotfire/install.exe" INSTALLDIR="$InstallDirectory" NODEMANAGER_REGISTRATION_PORT=17080 NODEMANAGER_COMMUNICATION_PORT=17443 SERVER_NAME=localhost SERVER_BACKEND_REGISTRATION_PORT=19080 SERVER_BACKEND_COMMUNICATION_PORT1=9443 NODEMANAGER_HOST_NAMES=$HostNames1 -silent -log "install.log"
} 

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $NodeIP -ScriptBlock ${function:nodeManagerUpgrade} -argumentlist ($ServiceName,$InstallDirectory,$HostNames) -credential $credentials
```

I can run the code contained in the function directly on the remote server and it works correctly. However, when I try and run it from the central server through `WinRM/Invoke-Command` within a function, it fails giving me this error:

```
The term 'X:/downloads/spotfire/install.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

Is it possible to run an executable using PowerShell on a remote server?

Comment: I take your point, I'm really just running an exe with parameters - so you think the only issue is the full UNC path isn't there?

Comment: Ok, that's great - that has worked for the mapped drive issue, thank you for that.  Further down my script though I need to run another file that is on the C:/ drive of the remote machine, and I'm getting the same error.  Do you know if it's possible to do that without creating a folder share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executable path is based on a *drive letter*, `X:`.

However, in remote sessions *mapped* drives (drives connected to network shares) aren't available by default, so you have two options:

- Establish a (temporary) drive mapping with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) before calling the executable (e.g., `$null = New-PSDrive X FileSystem \\foo\bar`)
- More simply, use the full *UNC* path of the target executable (e.g. 
  `& \\foo\bar\downloads\spotfire\install.exe ...`)

If the target executable isn't actually accessible from the remote session, you'd have to copy it there first, which requires establishing a remote session explicitly and using 
[`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) `-ToSession` - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp#example-5--copy-a-file-to-a-remote-computer) for an example.